# Loop though a data frame and create a model for each column which is evaluated on the same testing set

Tags: r, loops, dataframe, iterator, modeling

I have a data frame with 20 plus columns, and for each of these columns I would like to create a glm model which I then evaluate on the same testing set. Here is my attempt:

```
# Train-test splitting
smp_size <- floor(0.70 * nrow(x))
index <- sample(seq_len(nrow(x)),size = smp_size)
train <- x[index, ]
test <- x[-index, ]

for (i in 1:22) {

   names(train)[names(train) == names(train[i])] <- 'variab'
   names(test)[names(test) == names(test[i])] <- 'variab'

   mod <- glm(Y ~ variab, family = binomial, data = train)

  assign(paste0("val", sep = "_", letters[i]), as.numeric(performance(
    prediction(predict(mod, newdata = test, type = "response"),test$Y), 
    measure = "auc")@y.values[[1]]))
}
```

However this doesn't work, it just assigns the name "variab" to each column and ends up running the same model for each column. How can I make this loop iterate though each column in the data frame?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an idea for you.  I hope this meets your needs.  I don't know where your `performance()` or `prediction()` functions came from so I removed them from my example.

```
data(iris)
predictors <- names(iris)[-1]
response <- names(iris)[1]

# due to a ill chosen example data:
iris[,response] <- iris[,response]/max(iris[,response])

# sample
smp_size <- floor(.7*nrow(iris))
set.seed(20171212)
idx <- sample(seq_len(nrow(iris)), size=smp_size)
train <- iris[idx,]
test <- iris[-idx,]


for (i in predictors) {
  tmp.test <- data.frame(pred=get(i,test), resp=get(response, test))
  tmp.train <- data.frame(pred=get(i,train), resp=get(response, train))


  mod <- glm(resp ~ pred, family=binomial, data=tmp.train)

  assign(paste0("val", sep="_", i), data.frame(predicted=as.numeric(predict(mod, newdata=tmp.test, type="response")), actual=get(response,test)))
  }
```

Basically, it's what you already did.  You were already using the `assign()` function, and I think of `get()` as its complement and equally useful.  I'm also a proponent of not using numerical indexes when possible and iterating through names when I use a loop because it's both simple and easy to write effective `cat()` messages.

Comment: Thank you for your response! The only thing is that when I run your code i get the following error message: "Warning messages:
1: In eval(family$initialize) : non-integer #successes in a binomial glm!
2: 'newdata' had 45 rows but variables found have 105 rows" is that normal?

Comment: This comes from the command: `predict(object=mod,newdata=test,type="response")`.  It actually appears that for some reason predict is not using test, but rather train for the newdata argument, despite an explicit argument otherwise.  I haven't encountered that before, but I will resolve it and edit my post.

Comment: The updated answer corrects the issue and works correctly.  Note, the assign statement in the loop has been changed to give you better results since I'm not using your original `performance()` or `prediction()` functions.  You shouldn't have an issue in your example with the 'non-integer successes' warning since your data is probably actually binary data (I chose poor example data).

Comment: Great thanks! You can also use a regular linear model for your example like `mod <- lm(resp ~ pred, data=tmp.train)`, but it works great!